# Why do nslookup result differ when adding www?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

[image: nslookup result for google.com and www.google.com]

See image above depicting different results for `google.com` and `www.google.com`.

Any ideas why `nslookup` is behaving this way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because google has different DNS records for the root zone and the www zone.